# Colab's TensorFlow 2 Changes back to Tensorflow 1 After Runtime Restart

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I restarted TF from 1.15 to TF2 using the command:

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.0
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

However, when I restart my colab notebook ( running above cell commenting out the first line),

It say my TF version is 1.15?

What should I do so that tensorflow remain at version 2?

Thank you,

CS

Answer (score 3):

Magic command is an option as well:

```
try:
  # Use the %tensorflow_version magic if in colab.
  %tensorflow_version 2.x
except Exception:
  pass

import tensorflow as tf
```

Found the code from Udacity example: https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/courses/udacity_intro_to_tensorflow_for_deep_learning/l02c01_celsius_to_fahrenheit.ipynb#scrollTo=-ZMgCvSRFqxE

Answer (score 1):

Put your installation command `! pip install tensorflow==2.0` in its own code cell and the imports in a separate cell after the installation cell.

If you wish your installation to be saved, save it to google drive, and do as follows:
After running `! pip install tensorflow==2.0`, in a cell below it run;

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
! pip freeze --local > /content/drive/My\ Drive/installed.txt

#`then in another cell run` (this is what you'll need to run always to restore your installations)

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
! pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall `cat/content/drive/My\ Drive/installed
```

Then follow the link to get the access token to mount your drive.

Comment: Thank you. Sometime, it seems Colab runs code concurrently. For instance if I have {del variable, then var = some process} in a cell, then it say NameError: name 'variable' is not defined!

Comment: Colab runs code sequentially..For your case above running ```del var``` before ```var = (something)``` will definitely throw an error because your trying to delete ```var``` before declaring it so it doesn't exist yet in memory.

Comment: The variable was defined already in higher cell. I will send out my code if I find it. Thank you.

Comment: This does not work. The next day, I am running the notebook, It says 1.15.0!

Comment: If you want a persistent installation you may also refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253498/how-do-i-install-a-library-permanently-in-colab
but soon TF 2.0 will be the default for colab

Comment: Thank you. I see what is going on!

Comment: Just remember that colab doesn't offer persistent disk storage.

Answer (score 0):

from **future** import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

```
try:
  # Use the %tensorflow_version magic if in colab.
  %tensorflow_version 2.x
except Exception:
  pass

import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np
import logging
logger = tf.get_logger()
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```