# Can't install the Fastai library permanently on Colab

Tags: pip, installation, google-colaboratory

I've been doing the Intro to ML for Coders course by Fastai and I use Google's Colab. I love it, but I have a huge problem with it: Every time I re-open a notebook, I have to install the Fastai library, which takes a lot of time. I tried the top answer in   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253498/how-do-i-install-a-library-permanently-in-colab)  post but here's what happens: When I want to install the Fastai library, I need to install the 0.7.0 version so I can do the course so I do  
`!pip install --target=$nb_path fastai==0.7.0`

and I don't have to re-install it for a while(maybe 1 hour) even if I close my notebook but after that, I can't do

```
import fastai.structured
```

but I can import `fastai.imports`. I'm guessing this is because for some reason, after 1 hour, Colab switches to Fastai 1.0(maybe it updates?). That would explain why I can't access `fastai.structured` because it's in the older version, but I can still use the files in Fastai 1.0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which course are you using that uses the 0.7 version of the library?

Comment: @BobSmith [This](http://course18.fast.ai/ml.html)