# Tensorflow, python, google colab, google drive

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I am trying to train tensorflow object detection model on Google Colab. I installed the Tensorflow API on google colab as per instructions given in GitHub and after successfull installation I saved everything on Google Drive. But not I can not use that installation that I have to install everything again.

Is there any way to save Google Colab installations on Drive for later use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a library permanently in Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253498/how-do-i-install-a-library-permanently-in-colab)

Comment: actually no because every session you start leads to use a different machine but colab machines are basically linux pc so you can write linux command line code in your notebook in order to install tensor flow object detection api correctly every time you run it