# Permanent Library Colab - Dependencies

Tags: pip, installation, google-colaboratory

I am trying to install a permanent library in Google Colaboratory. I am following the instructions listed at [How do I install a library permanently in Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253498/how-do-i-install-a-library-permanently-in-colab)

```
!pip install --target=$'/content/gdrive/My Drive/PythonLibs/' --upgrade pycuda
!pip install --target=$'/content/gdrive/My Drive/PythonLibs/' --upgrade pydicom
```

I am running into an issue that the dependencies are not compatible with Colab.

```
Successfully built pycuda pytools
ERROR: google-colab 1.0.0 has requirement six~=1.12.0, but you'll have six 1.14.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: datascience 0.10.6 has requirement folium==0.2.1, but you'll have folium 0.8.3 which is incompatible.
ERROR: albumentations 0.1.12 has requirement imgaug<0.2.7,>=0.2.5, but you'll have imgaug 0.2.9 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: decorator, appdirs, six, numpy, pytools, MarkupSafe, mako, pycuda
Successfully installed MarkupSafe-1.1.1 appdirs-1.4.3 decorator-4.4.2 mako-1.1.2 numpy-1.18.2 pycuda-2019.1.2 pytools-2020.1 six-1.14.0
WARNING: The following packages were previously imported in this runtime:
  [decorator,numpy]
You must restart the runtime in order to use newly installed versions.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement upgrade (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for upgrade
```

Is there a way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your installation command. It should be `--upgrade`, not `-- upgrade`. Remove the space and the command should work.

Comment: The incompatible requirements errors are not an issue unless you are using the libraries mentioned in the errors. The error corrected by removing the space was a big issue, because it was preventing pydicom from being installed. Are you unable to use the installed packages?