# How do I install a module (RDKIT) permanently in Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, rdkit

How do I install a library permanently in Colab?

I followed the accepted answer from this thread

[How do I install a library permanently in Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253498/how-do-i-install-a-library-permanently-in-colab)

```
# first install gcsfuse
%%capture
!echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt gcsfuse-bionic main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list
!curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
!apt update
!apt install gcsfuse

%%writefile /key.json
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "kora-id",
  "private_key_id": "xxxxxxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxxxxxx==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "colab-7@kora-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "100380920993833371482",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/colab-7%40kora-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}

%env GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/key.json


!mkdir /content/my-bucket
!gcsfuse my-bucket /content/my-bucket

import sys
nb_path = '/content/my-bucket'
sys.path.insert(0, nb_path)
# Do this just once
!pip install --target=$nb_path jdc
```

RDKIT installation I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERvUf_lNopo

```
# Install RDKit. Takes 2-3 minutes
!wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
!time bash ./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!time conda install -q -y -c anaconda python=3.7
!time conda install -q -y -c conda-forge rdkit
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code, which avoid conda and can install rdkit in 6 seconds

```py
url = 'https://anaconda.org/rdkit/rdkit/2018.09.1.0/download/linux-64/rdkit-2018.09.1.0-py36h71b666b_1.tar.bz2'
!curl -L $url | tar xj lib
!mv lib/python3.6/site-packages/rdkit /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/
x86 = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
!mv lib/*.so.* $x86/
!ln -s $x86/libboost_python3-py36.so.1.65.1 $x86/libboost_python3.so.1.65.1
```

Update: I made a custom tarball that we can just extract them. Taking only 1.7s to install

```py
!curl -L bit.ly/rdkit-colab | tar xz -C /
```

You can also use my `kora` library.

```py
!pip install kora
import kora.install.rdkit
```