# How to permanently install a library in Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use the [joeymt](https://github.com/joeynmt/joeynmt) lbrary in Google Colab, which I installed in Google Drive, so that I don't have to install each time I work on the project. There is a solution described here: [How do I install a library permanently in Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253498/how-do-i-install-a-library-permanently-in-colab), which I follow along, but in the last step, when I try to run the training program, I get an error.

This is what I've tried:

I am mounting drive and inserting the path like described in the mentioned post like this:

```
import os, sys 
from google.colab import drive
#drive.mount('/content/drive')
nb_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/another_location'

if nb_path not in sys.path:
  sys.path.insert(1,nb_path)
```

`sys.path` then looks like this:

```
['',
 '/content/drive/MyDrive/another_location',
 '/content',
 '/env/python',
 '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/root/.ipython']
```

I then installed joeynmt from source using `! git clone https://github.com/joeynmt/joeynmt.git` and then `! git checkout 4b73db1`) with no error at the location in drive.

```
%cd joeynmt
!pip3 install --target=$nb_path .
```

In the Google Drive folder are now joeynmt and all its installed dependencies.

Now when I try to run `train`:

```
import joeynmt
!python -m joeynmt train /path_to_yaml_config_file
```

it throws the error

```
/usr/bin/python3: No module named joeynmt
```

Normally, if I'd just install joeynmt with `cd joeynmt pip3 install .` joeynmt would get installed into `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/joeynmt` and the command above would work just fine and start the training routine.

If I run `'joeynmt' in sys.modules` I get `True`, so what am I missing? I somehow think the path I inserted into the sys.path list is getting ignored? Or why does it say `No module named joeynmt`?

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning`, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Try updating to python 3.9 and upgrading pip

Comment: I see at least two differences between your commands and the commands recommended in the answer to the question you linked: you are cloning and installing from local sources and you are appending the notebook path to the position 1 instead of 0. Do you have the same problem if you use identical commands?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong tag. I had the same problem with the direct pip installation and with the path at position 0. But I managed to achieve what I wanted by switching to the directory in Google Drive where joeynmt got installed. Running then `!python -m joeynmt train /path_to_yaml_config_file` worked. I still don't know though why importing doesn't work.

Comment: Can you do something like ``conda install -p path_to_your_dir``

Comment: @JonahG the package I'm mainly interested in (joeynmt) is not available for installation with conda. I could use pip within a conda env to install joeynmt, but this might cause problems if I install other packages with conda within the same env. i will for now leave it like this.