# How can i permantly save a lib in Google Drive and load it from there in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I mounted my project in Google Colab with Google Drive and I want to load a library to my project. I tried the advise from this topic: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253498/how-do-i-install-a-library-permanently-in-colab)

Unfortunately i get this error:

[image: ERROR]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os, sys
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/mnt')
nb_path = '/content/mnt/MyDrive/Library'
sys.path.insert(0,nb_path)
```

and for installing any library from pip, use:

```
pip install --target=$nb_path jdc
```

where jdc is the library

This will install the library in 'Library' folder in your drive

Comment: I solved it by mounting using drive.mount('/content/gdrive/') and then just set a PATH as 'nb_path' from my drive and then !pip install --target=$nb_path git+link_from_Github.git