# How to permanently install Rapids on Google colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Is there a way to install Rapids permanently on Google colab? I tried many solutions given on StackOverflow and other websites but nothing is working. This is a very big library and it is very frustrating to download this every time I want to work on colab.

I tried this code from Rapids but it is also not working. When I close colab and start again later, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cudf'.`

```
# Install RAPIDS
!git clone https://github.com/rapidsai/rapidsai-csp-utils.git
!bash rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/rapids-colab.sh stable

import sys, os, shutil

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/')
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_NVVM'] = '/usr/local/cuda/nvvm/lib64/libnvvm.so'
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_LIBDEVICE'] = '/usr/local/cuda/nvvm/libdevice/'
os.environ["CONDA_PREFIX"] = "/usr/local"
for so in ['cudf', 'rmm', 'nccl', 'cuml', 'cugraph', 'xgboost', 'cuspatial']:
  fn = 'lib'+so+'.so'
  source_fn = '/usr/local/lib/'+fn
  dest_fn = '/usr/lib/'+fn
  if os.path.exists(source_fn):
    print(f'Copying {source_fn} to {dest_fn}')
    shutil.copyfile(source_fn, dest_fn)
# fix for BlazingSQL import issue
# ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/../../libblazingsql-engine.so)
if not os.path.exists('/usr/lib64'):
    os.makedirs('/usr/lib64')
for so_file in os.listdir('/usr/local/lib'):
  if 'libstdc' in so_file:
    shutil.copyfile('/usr/local/lib/'+so_file, '/usr/lib64/'+so_file)
    shutil.copyfile('/usr/local/lib/'+so_file, '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/'+so_file)
```

A solution has been suggested but which uses pip to install libraries - [How do I install a library permanently in Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253498/how-do-i-install-a-library-permanently-in-colab) but Rapids can't be installed using pip. It can only be installed using Conda. This is the code to install it.

```
conda create -n rapids-0.19 -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge \
    rapids-blazing=0.19 python=3.7 cudatoolkit=11.0
```

I tried to include the google drive path(`nb_path`) to this code using the --prefix flag as suggested by the above link `!pip install --target=$nb_path jdc` but I am getting a `syntax error`.

Can anyone tell me how to set this nb_path to the `conda create` code above?

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem I tried this method. Rapids can't be installed using pip. I have to use conda. so, when I try to specify the target using the conda --prefix flag I am getting the syntax error. I tried to resolve this using other posts on stackoverflow but I am still getting the error. This is the code for installing - conda create -n rapids-0.19 -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge \
    rapids-blazing=0.19 python=3.7 cudatoolkit=11.0
Can you tell me how to specify the target in it.

Comment: In your question, you may want to highlight that 1) you need to use conda and not pip, and 2) the linked answer does not help. I don't know the answer, but hopefully you will get some useful feedback. By the way, there is a similar [question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/74248/google-colab-conda-packages-permanently-installation) with no accepted solution.

Comment: @bholaprasad, I'm going to try this method to expediate the installation of cupy 9.0.0, which is pip and takes almost as long as installing RAPIDS.  Thanks for sharing it.  Another potential issue is that a tarball of the full RAPIDS conda install is 8-14GB.  depending on what you pull in, which can overwhelm the free 15GB of Google Storage that most people have.  Hopefully we have this revised for the upcoming 21.06 release.  If you want a deeper dive into how RAPIDS conda install works, hit me up on slack with the link I sent in my answer yesterday!

Answer (score 4):

For reference, the conda target path for RAPIDS install is `/usr/local`.  We use a different location in the RAPIDS-Colab install script to get it to work.

At the moment, I'm not aware of any way for a user to permanently install RAPIDS into Google Colab.  Google Colab isn't designed for the purpose of persisting libraries - or any data for that matter- that aren't preinstalled in the environment.  While you have a decent looking workaround there for pip libraries and datasets with Google Drive mounting, with RAPIDS, it is a little more tricky as we update quite a bit of the Colab environment in order to get it to even install RAPIDS. What you propose is an interesting path to explore. We do [encourage and work with RAPIDS community members in our Slack channel](https://join.slack.com/t/rapids-goai/shared_invite/zt-qoxnow9v-_mnN7zH7z4y3mx%7E_YrJW6w) who try new methods and improve some of our community code like the [RAPIDS-Colab installation script.](https://github.com/rapidsai-community/rapidsai-csp-utils)

Just remember, the RAPIDS + Google Colab effort was never meant to be more than a fun, easy way to "Try RAPIDS out".  For Google Cloud users, GCP is supposed to be the next step.  While it's heartening to see the usage grow over time, Google would need to create a Colab instance that has RAPIDS preinstalled for what you want to happen. You should let the know you want this by

1. Open any Colab notebook
2. Go to the Help menu and select ”Send feedback...”

In the meantime, if you need a ready-to-go instance, there are some inexpensive, RAPIDS-enabled, quick start options on the horizon.

Comment: I am getting several files not found errors even though all the files exist. -
python: can't open file 'rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/env-check.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: I'm updating the colab script as we have just released 21.06.  Should be fixed by midday