# pip install -r requirements to a specific directory in Colab

Tags: python, installation, pip, google-colaboratory, requirements.txt

I have found that I can pip install packages to a certain directory using:

```
!pip install --target='/content/drive/Mydrive/requirements' <package_name>
```

In the above case, I can see <package_name> in the folder '/content/drive/Mydrive/requirements'. However, when I install packages from a file, 'requirements.txt', the packages do not go into the target directory, namely:

```
!pip install --target='/content/drive/Mydrive/requirements' -r requirements.txt
```

Does not install the packages in 'requirements.txt' into '/content/drive/Mydrive/requirements'.

Can somebody please help? Thanks!

Comment: Your second command should work - verify that `requirements.txt` has been uploaded to the working directory and is successfully being used by the command. Could you also provide the output of running that command?

Comment: You may also get the answer you're looking for in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253498/how-do-i-install-a-library-permanently-in-colab

Answer (score 0):

I realized what was needed ... (below)

!pip install -r requirements.txt -t "target_dir"

I think where the "-r" flag is seemed to matter, but then again I had tried that but it didn't work before. However, what I have here does work.

Comment: `-r` is not a flag, it's an option that requires a single argument — requirements file; so `-r requirements.txt` is the whole thing.

Answer (score -1):

```
pip3 install "package_name" -t "target_dir"
```

Comment: This at least gets some stuff populating my folder in '/content/drive/Mydrive/requirements'. Thanks. ... Apparently I can't upvote you, just made my account.

Comment: @user1029384756 `-t` is equivalent to `--target`. This post does not answer your question for installing a `requirements.txt` file. It just installs a package called `package_name` using the same `--target` parameter you used.

Comment: Ah. I see, let me post what actually worked for me below, I realize now