# Google colab pip install

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

If I install packages on google-colab with

```
!pip install package_name
```

Will they be stored somewhere on my laptop or is everything stored online?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider this suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253498/how-do-i-install-a-library-permanently-in-colab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data will only store in the session you are currently in if you are using Google’s server, nothing will download to your machine unless you are using Colab to connect to your local runtime.

Comment: I uploaded a notebook on colab so I don't think I'm using Colab to connect to my local runtime unless it does it by default? Nothing is stored on my laptop then?

Comment: If you uploaded a notebook to Colab and you run the notebook using Google’s server, packages installed will be lost if you disconnect from your current runtime.

Comment: What does 'disconnect from your current runtime' mean?

Comment: Please checking following documentations: 1. https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html 2. https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html