# How to save the pip environment on google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

On Google Colaboratory (it is like the jupyter note book),

I start my work after `pip install magenta`

However, it takes about 30 min.

So, I have to wait for installing this library every time.

Is there any method to save the environment with pip??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a library permanently in Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253498/how-do-i-install-a-library-permanently-in-colab)

Comment: It helps and solves my problem. thank you very much for your help