# How to Install Pytorch Permanently in Google Colab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, package, google-colaboratory

I want to install a specific version of Pytorch in Colab but I find every time I restart it I need to reinstall it again! It wastes time a lot.

My current installation code is this:

```
!pip3 install -target=$path --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu116 -U
```

It usually takes more than 15 mins to finish this, so I wonder if there is any solution that can permanently solve this? Note that I had tried the solution given here: [How do I install a library permanently in Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253498/how-do-i-install-a-library-permanently-in-colab), but it does NOT work. Thanks all in advance！