# How can I permanently keep a library in my Google Drive installed in Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have tried this following solution (on this ([How do I install a library permanently in Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253498/how-do-i-install-a-library-permanently-in-colab))):

```
import os, sys
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/notebooks')
nb_path = '/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/pyActigraphy'
os.symlink('content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks', nb_path)
sys.path.insert(0,nb_path)

!pip install --target=$nb_path pyActigraphy
```

And I can see the library folder in my drive when I browse the mounted drive tab on the left on Colab. Yet when I reset Colab the import fails. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: FYI: it should be `'/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/'`